# Magento - add the WYSIWYG editor to custom widget options

Tags: magento

it is possible to add the Magento WYSIWYG editor to custom widget options??

If yes how can I do that ?

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help solve your problem: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/176212/

Comment: Do you have any details on how you were albe to implement WYSIWYG in widget options? I'm not able to figure it out from the above link.

Comment: Link is gone now. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look here:
[Magento - add WYSIWYG editor to custom widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767894/magento-add-wysiwyg-editor-to-custom-widget)

I managed to get it work for widget options. Hope it helps you.