# Magento WYSIWYG editor error: Target element not found for content update

Tags: javascript, magento, wysiwyg

I added editor to widget. I used solution described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767894/magento-add-wysiwyg-editor-to-custom-widget/15953843#15953843). Everything works fine excepting inserting image to editor where widget is inserted.

When I open widget and save it or close it, I can not insert image into original editor because it lost reference. I get error "Target element not found for content update" when I try to insert image.

I checked browser.js and checked value for this.targetElementId inside getTargetElement function. It has value of closed widget editor and not original active editor. I tried to change this value just to see if this would solve the problem:

```
getTargetElement: function() {  
    this.targetElementId = 'myeditor_content';      
    if (typeof(tinyMCE) != 'undefined' && tinyMCE.get(this.targetElementId)) {
        if ((opener = this.getMediaBrowserOpener())) {
            var targetElementId = tinyMceEditors.get(this.targetElementId).getMediaBrowserTargetElementId();
            return opener.document.getElementById(targetElementId);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } else {                             
        return document.getElementById(this.targetElementId);
    }
},
```

but then other errors shows up in console.

```
TypeError: tinyMceEditors.get(...).getMediaBrowserOpener(...) is null
```

Is there any easy way to somehow destroy reference to old editor (editor from widget which was closed)?

Comment: For the Gallery viewer and Magento's WYSIWYG editor, you normally have to add some XML to your layout handler. Not done this with a widget before but I think you might find "<update handle="editor" />" might be useful. Any admin module I have created before which uses the image gallery part of TinyMCE has this snippet of XML in.

Comment: Any One have solution for this error

Answer (score 0):

Try to add editor handle to layout.

For example:

```
<default>
  <update handle="editor"/>
</default>
```